# How to pass multiple textbox value with same id and name to ajax query string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
<input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
<input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
<input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
```

Above is my code as you can see I have multiple textbox with same name and id. now I was using php without the ajax function for submission. Using the foreach and json_encode as this is for the travel booking plan I am saving those value in a single database column. Below is my php code for the query I am using.

```
foreach($_POST['b_destinations'] as $p_destination) {
    $pdata[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$p_destination);
}
$pData[] = $pdata;
$b_destinations = json_encode($pData);
```

I was saving this form without the ajax but now I am going to use ajax for the submission of the form. how can i pass this multiple textbox value with same name and id to ajax datastring and then post it to my php query

Comment: Simply put, do not have multiple DOM elements with the same ID: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: You can use `document.getElementsByName` to get the value using javascript

Comment: @David sir,i need to text boxes with same id as they are generated dynamically. i now how to do the foreach loop for php but how to do it for ajax and i am using post function.

Comment: You can still generate unique IDs by simply adding on the index (if it's a loop) like id = 'title-' + i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comment above I really recommend to not have the same id for elements DOM, it must be unique.

Here is the solution for the post above:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
    var b_destinations = document.getElementsByName('b_destinations[]');
    var b_destinationsArr= [];

    b_destinations.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.value);
        b_destinationsArr.push(element.value);
    });

    var data = JSON.stringify(b_destinationsArr);
    
    //you have to change the url data here
    var url = "https://your.url.here";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
    //the same above
    //$.post( url, data );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" onSubmit="return handleClick()">
    <input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="b_destinations[]" id="title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can you also please help me with the other query i have posted, The error is quite funny don't know why it's happening. related with the form here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444546/getting-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-and-403-error-when-submitting-form

Answer (score 1):

Id is doesn't matter. You can use the given name to pass multiple values,

```
var b_destinations = document.getElementsByName('b_destinations[]');
var b_destinationsArr= [];
for(var i=0;i<b_destinations.length;i++)
    b_destinationsArr[] = b_destinations[i].value;
 // Ajax call with b_destinationsArr array in POST action
```

Comment: will try it and let you know.